# openpyxl row iterator ignores row_offset argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to sift through tons of worthless data, and I want to give the user the opportunity to set the offset herself. The the code ultimately ends up looking like:

```
master_rows = self.worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=10000)
```

However upon calling `next(master_rows)[0]`, the output turns out:

```
RawCell(row=1, column='A', coordinate='A1', [...] )
```

Basically, the offset seems to be completely ignored, it always starts from 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/src/22d4b2135553f0a26f931e95c6021c4c2302f494/openpyxl/reader/iter_worksheet.py#cl-117), if you don't pass `range_string`, then `iter_rows` will read all cols and rows in the sheet. In other words, `row_offset` will take effect if `range_string` is provided.

For example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


# printing coordinates of all rows and cols
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=2):
    for cell in row:
        print cell.coordinate


# printing coordinates from "A3:E5" range
for row in ws.iter_rows(range_string="A1:E3", row_offset=2):
    for cell in row:
        print cell.coordinate
```

Comment: this + `range_string=ws.calculate_dimension()` did exactly what I required it to do.